# Storing Bob encrypted data, and send them to Alice (who must be able to decrypt the content)

Tags: encryption, end-to-end-encryption

I need to develop a website where a user (Bob) send text, image, or video content to my website. After some time, I need to send this data to another user of his choice (Alice).

I want to encrypt user data before storing them on my website to preserve user privacy. I don't want to be able to decrypt these files/store the key.

But is there a way to do this? Bob will have had no contact with Alice, so in my eyes it's complicated.

Comment: What you are describing is a 'zero-knowledge' system, where information is encrypted and decrypted on the client side (in-browser, using javascript), so that only encrypted content reaches your server.  This is exactly what the Web Crypto API was designed for.  See https://www.encryptedsend.com/ for a use-case similar to what you describe.

Comment: But Bob and Alice need to have a contact right ? In my case, they don't interact. Bob sends me data. After some days/months I send the data to Alice. Is it possible with Web Crypto API ?

Comment: Yes.  When Alice registers, she sends her public key to the server.  Before Bob sends the data to the server, he encrypts it using Alice's public key.  The server stores the encrypted data, until it is time to send it to Alice.  When Alice receives the encrypted data, she decrypts it using her private key.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to specify that Alice must not know in advance that she will receive a message. So she can't registers. It must be a surprise. But, I think this is not possible with these constraints.

Answer (score 2):

**Option A:**

- Bob uploads data to your site. It is stored encrypted with a key only known by Bob.
- After some days/months, you notify Alice that there's some data to be received. Alice registers on your website (generating a public key).
- Bob *authorizes* Alice account to read the data (uses their public to encrypt the secret from step 1).
- The actual data can now be received by Alice.

Drawbacks:

- Bob needs to trust that the account registered by Alice is actually owned by his dear Alice, not by e.g. an imposter from your company.
- Bob needs to authorize Alice account (give her the key) after she registered.

**Option B:**

- Bob uploads his data to your site. You provide Bob a link to download, containing the key.
- Days/months later, *Bob* sends the link to Alice.

Drawbacks:

- Bob itself needs to send that link to Alice. Or someone else on behalf of Bob e.g. he could program an email to be sent in 3 months (if supported by his provider).
- Anyone in possession of that link could access the data. This could be easily solved by having your site verify Alice identity (you check that the access is performed by Alice *and* she needs the link for decryption).

If Alice already had an encryption key (such as a PGP key), that could be used directly, but it is unlikely that a normal user has one.

Comment: Thank you for your time ! Unfortunately, it will not be possible to Bob to send a link to Alice, because Bob will be dead. In fact, it is for post mortem messages. So I don't see any chance to achieve a zero knowledge storage in this situation: Bob is dead, I can't store the key, and it should be a surprise for Alice. In this case the only person which have the key is the dead Bob :o. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case. Maybe they can leave a letter (containing the 'password') to be provided after his dead, though? Or use a password which Alice can guess (e.g. place we went to in our honeymoon) but (hopefully)  your service can't. They won't be specially good but I guess that's what it takes.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will think about these solutions.

Comment: @Slot Bitwarden currently does this.  Alice is alive, Bob is alive they exchange keys up front. Bob uploads data, Alice can request the data in the event Bob died.  If Bob is not dead he can click the "Reject" button on the email.  If Bob does not click "Reject" for a preconfigured amount of time Alice is sent the data and decrypt it w/ the key they exchanged while they where both alive.

Comment: If you don't want Alice to have any knowledge of this data or the setup before Bob's untimely demise it would require a trusted third party to take Alice's place on initial setup (like a trusted legal counsel setup by Bob prior to death).